# непрерывный перебор массива

Tags: javascript

Помогите реализовать непрерывный перебор массива, что бы запуск и остановка перебора были по клику. Сейчас, по клику запускается перебор, и на `div` вешается класс `'markup-lighting'` через `toggle`. Так и нужно, но пробегает длину один раз и все, а мне нужно что бы после нажатия на `start-button`, происходила итерация постоянно, пока не нажму на другую кнопку, к примеру `stop - button`.
Код:

```
var startButton = document.querySelector('.start-button');
startButton.addEventListener("click", movement);

function movement() {
  function markup(i) {
    return function() {
      console.log(i);
      markupLeft[i].classList.toggle('markup-lighting');
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < markupLeft.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(markup(i), i * 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Используйте setInterval вместо setTimeout

Comment: Зачем в цикле интервалить один и тот же массив? И какой от этого смысл? Да и если это на то пошло, то нужно цикл делать в интервале, а не наоборот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение через `setInterval` и `clearInterval`:

```js
// кнопка старт и обработчик клика на нее
var startButton = document.querySelector('.start-button');
startButton.addEventListener("click", start);

// кнопка стоп и обработчик клика на нее
var stopButton = document.querySelector('.stop-button');
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stop);

// идентификатор таймера 
var timerId = null;

// заполним массив пятью элементами `div` (чтобы ваш пример кода работал в сниппете)
markupLeft = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  markupLeft.push(div);
};

// функция запуска - запоминаем `timerId` (кнопка Start)
function start() {
  // если таймер не запущен - запустить, иначе ничего не делать
  if (!timerId) {
    console.log('started');
    timerId = setInterval(movement, 1000); // через секунду снова запустим
  }
}

// функция остановки - останавливаем по `timerId` (кнопка Stop)
function stop() {
  // если таймер запущен - остановить, иначе ничего не делать
  if (timerId) {
    console.log('stopped');
    clearInterval(timerId); // остановить выполенение функции в `setInterval`
    timerId = null; // обнулить таймер
  }
}

// далее ваш старый код без изменений
function movement() {
  function markup(i) {
    return function() {
      console.log(i);
      markupLeft[i].classList.toggle('markup-lighting');
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < markupLeft.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(markup(i), i * 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="start-button">Start</button>
<button class="stop-button">Stop</button>
```

> [`setInterval`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval) -  запускает выполнение функции и регулярно повторяет её
>   через указанный интервал времени, возвращает числовой идентификатор
>   таймера `timerId`, который можно использовать для отмены действия.
>   Остановить исполнение можно вызовом [`clearInterval(timerId)`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-cleartimeout).

Comment: все же не корректно работает ваш вариант, попробуйте нажать пару раз на старт, а потом остановить.

Comment: @Vitaliy - приведенный пример не конечное решение. Думаю, что вы догадались, что нажав несколько раз кнопку старт - вы запустите несколько таймеров и в `timerId` будет лишь последний таймер, соответственно - остановится только последний, а другие будут утеряны и продолжат выполнение. Думаю, что с нюнсами вы и сами сможете справиться :) Добавил простую проверку в пример кода в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Для непрерывного можете использовать не for, а while(b), где

```
b = true;
```

при нажатии на кнопку start. При нажатии на кнопку finish

```
b = false;
```

Либо же после цикла for проверить, если счетчик дошел до конца массива, то перекинуть его на 0